# Windows Installer keeps popping up whenever the application is opened

Tags: installation, installshield

Our software is being installed on Windows 2008 machine, however when a user tries to run the application the installer pops-up again and then installs again.

**This is What happens:**

The network administrator gives the user Admin rights, then installs the software on the user's machine. Then the network administrator takes away the user's Admin rights, but gives him permission to all folders where that is needed to run the program.

Now when the user tries to run the application the installer appears again and installs, then the software opens.

We suspect that this is a Permissions problem on the user's machine... But somehow cannot get this to work.

Any ideas on how to go about this problem...

Comment: Enable logging and maybe you will find out why Windows Installer starts up again: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300

Comment: Did you find problem and solution?

Comment: No, my company handed the problem over to Microsoft support, once they find the solution I will post it up.

Comment: But strangely enough, something similar happened to me, when I mistakenly added the wrong merge module to the installer...